# Gettext - Detecting duplicate messages with different variable key names

Tags: localization, internationalization, gettext, po

I have recently started i18n my django project, and I have `.po` files. However in my templates, I have done things suboptimaly. I have just copied the local variable name for something that appears a lot. So I have near-duplicates in .po file, like `%(num)s messages` and `%(num_messages)s messages` and `%d messages`. I should have written them all the same way, so that there is only one translation.

Is there any way/software that can read my `.po` file and tell me these messages that I should merge?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid I do not know any tool that has such functionality built in. What you could try to do instead is use your favourite reg-ex aware text editor and Excel:

1) Paste the content of your po file into column A of a new spreadsheet

2) Open the content of your po file in your favourite reg-ex aware text editor and try to reduce all long variables to their shortest variant: in your example you could replace `%\([^\)]+\)s` by `%d`. Or replace all variables by some string that does not occur anywhere else, like RORYS_PLACEHOLDER.

3) Paste the content of your po file with normalized or no more variables into column B of the spreadsheet.

4) Set a filter for strings that start with `msgid`, then let Excel highlight duplicate values in column B. (Home > Conditional Formatting > Highlight Cell Rules > Duplicate Values in Excel 2013)

Of course your po file may be too complex for this approach, but it is worth a try.